# ComboBox resgatar o valor do ID

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

```
public void SalvarProfessor(Professor professores)
        {
            try
            {
                AbrirConexao();

                comando = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO professores (nome, idade, genero, email, id_especialidade) VALUES (@nome, @idade, @genero, @email, @id_especialidade)",conexao);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", professores.Nome);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idade", professores.Idade);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@genero", professores.Genero);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", professores.Email);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_especialidade", professores.Especialidade);



                comando.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception erro)
            {
                throw erro;
            }
            finally
            {
                FecharConexao();
            }
        }
private void SalvarProfessor(Professor professores)
        {
            RegistrosBLL professorBll = new RegistrosBLL();

            professores.Nome = tb_NomeProfessor.Text;
            professores.Idade = Convert.ToInt32(tb_IdadeProfessor.Text);
            professores.Genero = cb_GeneroProfessor.Text;
            professores.Email = tb_EmailProfessor.Text;
            professores.Especialidade = cbEspecialidade.Text;



            professorBll.SalvarProfessor(professores);

            LimparCampoProfessor();
            MessageBox.Show("Professor Cadastrado com sucesso!");
        }
```

Esse metodo é usado para salvar professor, mas preciso que o comboBox resgate o ID atraves do nome Listado nele, EX "Psicologia do Esporte":

Atualmente esta sendo mostrado assim[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso que o usuário cadastre o professor pelo Nome listado no `comboBox` e não Digitando o ID da especialidade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa preencher o ComboBox com os dados das especialidades:

Supondo que sua classe seja algo assim:

```
public class Especialidade
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Nome {get;set;}
}
```

Você deve obter uma lista de especialidades do banco de dados e atribui-la ao combobox:

```
List<Especialidade> lista = //...Select do banco....

cbEspecialidade.ValueMember = "Id";
cbEspecialidade.DisplayMember = "Nome";
cbEspecialidade.DataSource = lista;
```

Na hora de atribuir o valor, você pode pegar o item, que será uma especialidade ou o valor selecionado:

```
professores.Especialidade = cbEspecialidade.SelectedValue?.ToString();
```

ou

```
Especialidade objEsp =  cbEspecialidade.SelectedItem as Especialidade;
professores.Especialidade = objEsp.Id;
```

Você também pode usar uma DataGridViewComboBoxColumn pra exibir um combo no datagridview. Para popular ele, é exatamente igual.

Answer (score -1):

Crie uma View semelhante a esta:

create view Mostrar_Professor
as
select ID_PROF as CÓDIGO, NOM_PROF as NOME, IDADE, GENERO, EMAIL, tabespe.NOM_ESP as ESPECIALIDADE from tabelaprofessor tabprof 
join TabelaEspecialidade tabespe
on tabprof.ID_ESP = tabespe.ID_ESP

Crie um Procedimento semelhante a este:

DELIMITER $$ 
 CREATE PROCEDURE Mostrar_Professor()
   BEGIN
    select * from mostrar_professor;
   END $$
DELIMITER ;

Mude seu dataGridViewProdutos.DataSource para receber o procedimento Mostrar_Professor, tenho quase certeza que irá resolver seu problema.